# How to prevent system notifications (of all apps) from showing up during screenshare in Windows?

Tags: c#, uwp, screen

I'm using a UWP app and following the screen capturing as mentioned in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture

As a part of privacy, how can I programmatically disable or prevent system notifications from being captured during screenshare?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no API in UWP that can programmatically disable or prevent system notifications.

It is recommended that you enable “**Do not disturb**” in **Settings** >**System** >**Notifications**.

Comment: Got it . Thanks for the response. However just curious if it is programmatically possible to do this via Win32 API's keeping UWP out of picture ?

Comment: There is `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` for win32, but I tested it, `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` **does not work for UWP**. So, the best way right now is to go to Settings and manually turn on Do Not Disturb mode, or turn on it in the notification center which in the corner of the taskbar.

Comment: @Karthik Have you checked my last comment, hope it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that. I took a look at zoom windows app and I see an option in their Settings > Share Screen > Silence system notifications when sharing desktop. Just wondering if there are options if I go with a dedicated win32 app ?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't found a win32 API that can implement such a function on Win11. I also tried checking the registry for changes when I enabled Do Not Disturb but found nothing.